# Command line: Create line breaks after 'x' characters, plus white space

Tags: regex, text, command

I'm creating test samples of text of varying length, where each sample is separated by a line break. Currently I have 3mb+ files of text with no line breaks, only spaces. I was hoping for help with the proper reg expression to make sure no line breaks are cutting words in half.

I'm **very** new to using reg expressions. but I assumed that for i.e. lines of 300 character length, it would be somewhere in the ballpark of:

```
/.{300,}\s+/&\n/g
```

*(Apologies, I know this doesn't work!)*

---

**Note:** I know there are similar posts about this subject, but I'm relatively sure there's nothing out there that specifically addresses this scenario.

---

**Update**: Solved! Worked with this command:  `perl -lpe's/\b(.{80,300})\b/\1\n/g' file`

Comment: Did you try `{1,300}` instead?

Comment: do you HAVE to insert new lines that way? what is your goal? you could use a text editor with automatic wrapping, if you only want to look at it, for example...

Comment: Yeah the character length is pretty specific, I'm making a foray into some basic NLP stuff and running some tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there are no new lines already in the data? (if there are, the `.` dot character will not match them) If there are no newlines, something as simple as this might work:

```
s/\s(.{80,300})\s/$1\n/g
```

The 80 lower bound is just an arbitrary choice, that will rarely affect the outcome, if there are no newlines present. You can make 300 lower if you want shorter lines.

**Edit**: changed `\b` to `\s` which may be a better choice to avoid unexpected line breaks around non-word characters, as pointed out by @tchrist. Also, OP did not say he needed Perl backreference's, so tchrist changed `\1` to `$1`, which makes more sense for Perl.

Comment: Thanks this worked! I used: perl -lpe's/\b(.{80,300})\b/\1\n/g' file.txt > file2.txt and it worked beautifully.

Comment: @hmnrsrcs You really ought to use `$1` on the replacement side of the substitution. Also, you probably want whitespace with `\s`, not `\b`, because you get weirdness otherwise.

Comment: @tchrist: I tested this on a 3meg file of my own and didn't see any weirdness. Could you describe what you mean? Also note that the OP said 'Solved! Worked with this command: `perl -lpe's/\b(.{80,300})\b/\1\n/g`' file' So are you sure about changing `\1` to `$1`? I don't mind you editing the answer, but just make sure you're right when the OP says the answer I posted worked for him.

Comment: @alan Add a `-w` and you will see.  And yes, I do know I’m right; honest. The weirdness is that a boundary is just a transition between word chars and nonword chars, not a space boundary. That means with something like `3+4 = 7` it could break around the plus but not around the equals. That’s not what you normally want.

Comment: @tchrist Well, in this particular use case, I think breaking around the `+` is the least of the OP's worries. But I would like you to teach me something: the OP did not say he was using Perl. So I used `\1` as the backreference. He said it worked. Why did it work? Why did he not have to use `$1`. (I know next to nothing about Perl.)

Comment: @alan It worked because Perl grandfathers `sed` behavior in the RHS of a `s///` with respect to treatment of `\1`.  That is not something that works in normal double-quoted strings, which is really all the RHS is.